# "Where'd he learn that." "Where'd he learned that."

Tags: sentence-construction

> Where'd he learn that.
>   Where'd he learned that.

Which is correct? And please explain.

Comment: The *'d* is a contraction for *did*, an auxiliary verb. Auxiliary verbs may combine only with the plain form of the main verb (in this case *to learn*). So the second sentence is unacceptable.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.  You have an answer. That should go in the answer box.

Answer (score 1):

The 'd is a contraction for did, an auxiliary verb. Auxiliary verbs may combine only with the plain form of the main verb (in this case to learn). So the second sentence is unacceptable. – user105719

Answer (score -3):

The first sentence is non-standard. The auxiliary DO does not normally contract in Standard English. It should be *where did he learn that?*. The auxiliary DO can also occur as a proclitic as in *How d'ya know?*. And this is non-standard too.

The second sentence is grammatical. *-d* is a contraction of *had*: cf. *Where had he learned that?*.

Comment: https://www.lawlessenglish.com/learn-english/grammar/contractions-do/

Comment: @Accumulation I didn't say it was wrong. I said it was non-standard, just like the contraction of "does" in "what's it matter" and the reduction of "to" in "wanna". The website you cite is confusing informality and non-standard usage.

Comment: Non-standard is not the right term. It's just spoken form.